# Custom 404 Pages not being GZIPed in Apache

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-404, gzip

I've written myself a custom 404 page, but I've noticed that the page doesn't get GZIPed when served, when I return the status code 404. Even though I'm sure it should be.

(I'm redirecting all requests to index.php, then parsing the URI, and issuing 404's when needed through header(), so I'm not using ErrorDocument, although I've tested with ErrorDocument and the same problem happens.)

Does anyone know if this is this a known 'feature', a bug in PHP/Apache or my own code?

I'm using PHP5.5.9/Apach2.4.7 On Ubuntu, and Apache is configured to use mod_deflate.

This is a simple test script I've got:

```
<?php

header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not found");

print "WILL THIS BE GZIPED! ".str_repeat('X',500);

?>
```

If you comment out the header 404 (so that it gets a normal 200 response) it returns the page compressed fine.

I've also tried with the new `http_response_code(404);` command for PHP >=5.4, but that doesn't help.

I've tested in Chrome/Developer Tools and also directly with Curl to test if it gets compressed, and it doesn't. There is no Response Header 'Content-Encoding: gzip', so I'm guessing its Apache that's not compressing it.

Its not a major problem for me, obviously, as I hope to not get too many people trying to link to pages that generate a 404 error, but it would be good if it did compress correctly.

I guess I could do the compression myself in PHP, but wanted to see if it was a bug or me doing something wrong first.

(Note, you have to make sure the response is >256 bytes to get Apache to compress, so that's what the `str_repeat` bit is)

Comment: How are you enabling GZIP?

Comment: I have deflate enabled in the mods-enabled dir:
deflate.load:
LoadModule deflate_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
& deflate.conf:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml

Comment: Add `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");` at the beginning of your file to force gzip compression.

Comment: I did some testing, and this issue is not exclusive to PHP, `ErrorDocument 404 ...` has the same behavior. Looks to be specific to mod_deflate and/or Apache.

Comment: Thanks for the conformation Alexander, I'll post something on the Apache mail list and see what they say. I'll test for 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' and issue a manual ob_gzhandler for now. Thanks.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I'm stack with same problem

Comment: I reported it on the Apache website back in 2015, but no one ever commented back to me. It stills a problem now in 2017, so no one has fixed it. The only thing you can do is the method that was suggested above, and do the ob_gzhandler bit manually :(